# 14.04.2 hangs after updates installed

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, stable-release-updates

After I installed the latest updates to 14.04.2 (including the new linux kernel) my display was wacky and the computer hung as soon as I tried to do something. I tried reverting to the previous kernel version but that didn't help.  What to do next?

Second try at explaining my problem:

After I installed the latest updates to 14.04.2 (including the new linux kernel) my display was wacky and the computer hung as soon as I tried to do something. I tried reverting to the previous kernel version but that didn't help. What to do next?

I hope this is a clearer, more complete explanation of my problem. on the morning of May 22, my screen was displaying a dialog box announcing that security and other updates for my 14.04 OS were available. As I usually do, I expanded the list of updates to see what would be updated. Upon seeing that a new linux kernel (3.13.0-53, I think) was on the list I knew that a restart would be needed, so I closed my open applications and clicked the 'update now' button. Rather than wait for the update to complete, which I usually do, I went for coffee and errands with my wife. When I returned 2+ hours later I woke up the screensaver with my password and found the expected 'must restart to complete installation' dialog. I restarted. The restart took somewhat longer than usual and the icons down the left side of the screen were split in half and were missing pixels. I clicked on one and the computer froze, couldn't move the mouse, nothing. I powered down to restart and this time the restart took way longer but the screen looked more or less the same. I could move the mouse so I clicked on the button and the top right and tried to restart again from there. Nothing.

So I went to my Win7 computer and searched for a report of crashes after updating. I found one that indicated that reverting to a previous kernel might work, so I interrupted the next restart with a call to GRUB and chose to restart with the previous kernel in recovery mode. That led to screens that I had no clue how to deal with. So I tried again with the previous kernel, normal restart. That left me with what I had started with, a strange looking home screen and a computer that freezes on the first click of anything. Is that better?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what did you install and how.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write this anywhere it your post, but taggs say that you have an Nvidia graphics adapter. You can reinstall the driver from recovery console.

Boot using the last kernel in recovery mode. Then choose "root" from that menu. Then run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get purge nvidia*
apt-get install nvidia-331
reboot
```

The system will reboot, and let's hope that it will start OK.
Be careful with commands.